# MVC2: Is there an Html Helper for raw Html?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

Is there an Html helper that simply accepts and returns raw html? Rather than do something ugly like this:

```
<% if (Model.Results.Count > 0) { %><h2>Results</h2><% } %>
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
 <% if (Model.Results.Count > 0) { Html.RawHtml("<h2>Results</h2>") } %>
```

Not a whole lot cleaner, but I think it's a bit of an improvement. Does something like that exist? Or is there perhaps a better alternative to output raw html from within those escape characters than using Html helpers?

Comment: Now that I think about it, you would lose intellisense and html parsing capabilities by just using a literal string like that. With such a simple example as above, that's not really a big deal, but I guess with more complex html it might be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Response.Write should work. (Although maybe it's kind of taking a step back!) You should be able to create an extension method to do it. And maybe instead of using HTML string, you might want to build your markup in code [using the TagBuilder](http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/tutorial-35-cs.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

For MVC2:

```
<%: MvcHtmlString.Create("<h2>Results</h2>") %>
```

Found here:

[store and display html tags in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202218/store-and-display-html-tags-in-mvc)

Answer (score 1):

There is such helper now:

```
Html.Raw("<h2>Results</h2>")
```

Comment: It's only available in MVC3 and not in MVC2.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an HtmlHelper for whatever you're doing, you can return an MvcHtmlString built with a TabBuilder

Here an example of one that I use:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString AccountsDropDown(this HtmlHelper helper, string name,  object htmlAddributes = null, bool addNull = false, Guid? selected = null)
    {
        Account acc = HttpContext.Current.Session["account"] as Account;

        TagBuilder tb = new TagBuilder("select");

        tb.GenerateId(name);
        tb.Attributes["name"] = name;

        if (addNull)
            tb.InnerHtml += string.Format("<option value= '{0}'> {1} </option>", "", "None");


        Dictionary<Guid, String> accounts;

        if (acc.Master)
            accounts = db.Account.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);
        else
            accounts = db.Account.Where(x => x.Id == acc.Id).ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);

        foreach (var account in accounts)
            tb.InnerHtml += string.Format(
                "<option value= '{0}' {2}> {1} </option>", 
                account.Key, 
                account.Value,
                selected == account.Key ? " selected='selected' " : ""
            );

        return new MvcHtmlString(tb.ToString());
    }
```