# Is it possible to display raw Html from database in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a table in my db where one of the properties is an Html page (without the html, head and body tags), and I intend to put it in the middle of one of my views - say, I call a cotroller method that takes an argument, and return a view passing this html big string as the model. I searched for it (not much, I admit), and found the following method:

```
<%= System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(yourEncodedHtmlFromYouDatabase) %>
```

That was found [here in stackoverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300424/how-do-i-display-html-stored-in-a-database-from-an-asp-net-mvc-view) When I tried a similar razor aproach, I ended up with this:

```
@System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("<h1>Test</h1>")
```

That's the idea, but it didn't work quite as I planned.

Comment: What does `yourEncodedHtmlFromYouDatabase` look like? I'm guessing that the HTML `<h1>Test</h1>` would actually be encoded something like this: `&lt:h1&gt;Test&lt:/h1&gt;`.

Comment: Actually, it would be more like using tags. I don't have the db ready yet, but that's what we're planning to do, so I'm looking for options.

Comment: This question for MVC2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169805/mvc2-is-there-an-html-helper-for-raw-html

Answer (score 96, accepted):

All you need is: `@Html.Raw(yourEncodedHtmlFromYouDatabase)`

I'm assuming that the html in the database has been properly sanitized (or at least from a reliable source), because if not, you could be opening yourself up to cross-site scripting attacks.

The reason your approach didn't work is that Razor HTML-encodes output by default (every time you use `@` to display something). `Html.Raw` tells Razor that you trust the HTML and you want to display it without encoding it (as it's already raw HTML).

Comment: Thank you very much. As for security, I believe there's no such problem, since we'll be building this html ourselves.

Answer (score 12):

You can also return a HTMLString and Razor will output the correct formatting, for example.

```
@Html.GetSomeHtml()

public static HtmlString GetSomeHtml()
{
    var Data = "abc<br/>123";
    return new HtmlString(Data);
}
```

This will allow you to display HTML