# How do I render a dynamic string as html in MVC3 view (Razor)

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using `MVC3 Razor` for developing a web application.Am new to MVC3.
I just want to render a dynamic `string` which contains some html tags `into a view as html`.

How can I achieve this? if anybody knows please share..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to display raw Html from database in ASP.NET MVC 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798334/is-it-possible-to-display-raw-html-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [HtmlHelper.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method.

```
string myDynamicContent = "<b>This is bold</b>";

@Html.Raw(myDynamicContent)
```

Comment: Thanks Eric For such a fast and helpful response.