# Generate pages based on title and content in ASP.net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor

I am looking to do something that might not be possible, but I will leave it up to the community to decide that.

I have a table called content, in this table are the following: **Title** and **Content**.

Based on this information I would like the user to be able to input a title and their content and from the title a page is created so they can go to site.com/title and see the content for that page.

I am sure there is more to this, how ever that's where I require your guy's help. I am not looking to create a CMS, instead I am looking to create a piece of a CMS, the "page generation" part.

I don't have any code as this is an idea and I looking for a direction to take to produce the code.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a route with a hardcoded controller that takes a string (the **Title**) as a parameter.  Then in that controller, use the **Title** to pull the **Content** out of the database.  Pass the **Content** to the view (ensuring the HTML is sanitized) and display it.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "NotACMS",
    url: "{title}",
    defaults: new { controller = "NotACMS", action = "Index" }
);
```

Comment: Is there more information on how to do this? like MSDN docs? other stack questions and so on?

Comment: There is this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798334/is-it-possible-to-display-raw-html-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-3), which discusses displaying HTML from a database.  Everything else is regular, simple MVC code.