# Whats wrong with my routes and actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, razor, entity

I recently asked a question based on how to create pages based on the content table which contains the following: **Title** and **Content**. I followed the steps, to my understanding, in the [answer that was given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217901/generate-pages-based-on-title-and-content-in-asp-net-mvc3/16218201?noredirect=1#comment23194601_16218201).

I created a route like so:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "ContentManagement",
            "{title}",
            new { controller = "ContentManagement", action = "Index", title = "{title}" }
        );

    }
```

I am assuming I can do routes like this? where I can set up multiple routes? I am also assuming I can pass the title to to the controller action like I have done?

I then created the model:

```
namespace LocApp.Models
{
    public class ContentManagement
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
    }
}
```

from that I created a controller with an index action that looks as such:

```
    public ViewResult Index(string title)
    {
        using (var db = new LocAppContext())
        {
            var content = (from c in db.Contents
                           where c.title == title
                           select c).ToList();

            return View(content);

        }
    }
```

So then I created some content with the **title** of "bla" so when I visit site.com/bla I get an error that it cant find "bla/"

Can some one tell me what I am doing wrong? I would also, if you are familiar with the default layout of a asp.net mvc project with the tabs at the top, create a set of tabs that lead to the pages, based on the title in the database

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558541/what-kind-of-route-would-i-need-to-provide-vanity-urls?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that when you are using the title, the routing engine is matching it to the first route and trying to find a controller by that title.  We have implemented something similar and found that by explicitly defining what controllers are valid for the default route, it then processed request appropriately.  I gave an example of the controllers that we allow to fit our default route below (Home, Help and Error).

You probably also want to prevent people from giving the content the same **TITLE** as your root level controllers as that would blow this up pretty well.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
                new {controller = "Home|Error|Help"},
                new[] {"UI_WWW.Controllers"});

            routes.MapRoute(
                "ContentManagement",
                "{title}",
                new {controller = "ContentManagement", action = "Index"});    

            }
}
```