# MVC3 and virtual view without VirtualPathProvider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, virtualpathprovider

I have a MVC3 Application and I have few of my views content saved in database as string.
Now I need to create a virtual view and return this to the client.
I read that this can be done by VirtualPathProvider.
But wanted to know whether this can be done by RazorViewEngine or not.

EDIT1:
I have used a VPP as suggested in this link http://blog.rocketbase.co.uk/2011/04/asp-net-mvc-virtual-path-provider/ . And I registered it in the global.asax file. 
I have a pretty big web app which has many views which are physically present in the project too. So after registering the VPP in global.asax I find that

- every request in the web app goes via this VPP. Be it for physical or dynamic view. So isn't there be a performance hit for this? And cant we control this call to the VPP by tracking the URL?
- Also I have only .cshtml files in my project, but mvc tries to find .ascx, .aspx, .vbhtml etc etc files. Which again I feel will have a negative impact on the performance.

Comment: Yes you can.

Read this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798334/is-it-possible-to-display-raw-html-from-database-in-asp-net-mvc-3

Comment: No, that will just put some formatted html on the client. But I was looking for some way which will have allow me to send complete virtual view.

Answer (score 0):

The `RazorViewEngine` uses a virtual path provider (VPP) to locate files. The default VPP in ASP.NET locates files on disk. You can write a custom VPP that gets the view contents from a database. If you register the custom VPP in ASP.NET then MVC will certainly be able to compile, load, and render those views.

An alternative would be to write a completely new view engine - but that's no easy task. If you don't want to use a VPP then I think you'll need to write a custom view engine because the two built-in view engines certainly don't support this.

Comment: Thanks Elion, I understood what you said, I have edited my question. Please have a look at EDIT1 text above.