# ASP.NET MVC 5 - How do I get the stored HTML to render properly when returned to a page using a foreach loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and using tinymce editor to store HTML formatted data (for certain fields) to a SQL Server 2014 database.

The data is being returned to the page using a foreach loop, but the tags/markup are not being rendered as HTML and instead are showing up in the page as text.

CODE EX:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)</div>
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</div>
    <div>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</div>
}
```

How do I get the stored HTML to render properly when returned to the page?

Comment: Use `@Html.Raw()` if your values contain html tags

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7777718/6448640

Comment: When I replace the Html.Display with HTML.Raw I get the following error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: I have replaced the call with the following, but since I am a bit new to Razor, I do not think I have implemented it correctly because the markup is still being rendered as text : @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(item.Description))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw()`

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

This error can be avoid by using `Raw(@item.Category)`. Try:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {    
    <div>@Html.Raw(@item.Category)</div>
    <div>@Html.Raw(@item.Name)</div>
    <div>@Html.Raw(@item.Description)</div>
}
```

Comment: A word of caution. `Html.Raw()` introduces a risk of cross site scripting. You should use it only with trusted data.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {    
    <div>@Html.Raw(item.Category)</div>
    <div>@Html.Raw(item.Name)</div>
    <div>@Html.Raw(item.Description)</div>
}
```

You need to use Html.Raw as this render html content into page.