# store and display html tags in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I store post.content as html in database and how can I display with rendered html without tags. I am trying with following way, but it's not working. It can stored encode html  in database but its not displayed rendered html. Any best practice would be appreciated.

1)
//Saving post content in database as html

```
public ActionResult Edit(Post post, FormCollection obj)
        {               
          post.Content = Server.HtmlEncode(post.Content);
        }
```

2)
//Displaying post content to view

```
<%: System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.Content)%>
```

OR

```
<%: item.Content%>
```

Comment: value in database field = <p> <strong>hello</strong></p> how it can be displayed on view with paragraph and bold

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVC3/Razor:

```
@Html.Raw(item.Content)
```

MVC2/WebForms:

```
<%: MvcHtmlString.Create(item.Content) %>
```