# How to convert text into subscript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have to display a label with subscript, however It is not displaying the way it should.
Model:

```
 Forms = new List<DoubleKeyViewItem>()
                {
                    { new DoubleKeyViewItem() { Key = "NH4" , Name = "Other NH<sub>4</sub>" , Value = fer.Nut.Analysis.OtherNH4 } },                       
                }
```

View:

```
<label for=<%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListOfNuts[j].Forms[k].Name) %></label><br />
```

As of now the output looks like this: Other NH < sub>4< /sub>.
Is there any way i can get it to render the label as -> Other NH<sub>4</sub> ?

Comment: You need to make the label render html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have looked for some more time before asking, the answer is right here:
[store and display html tags in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202218/store-and-display-html-tags-in-mvc)

```
<%: MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.ListofNuts[j].Forms[k].Name)%>
```

gives me output as desired Other NH<sub>4</sub>.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Html.Raw(model => model.ListOfNuts[j].Forms[k].Name)
```